# Symfony2: No route found for "GET /genus/octopus/"

Tags: php, symfony

Doing my first app from http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony/
It's standart error, but I don't know how to debug it, cause in `debug:error` route `/genus/{genusName}` is exists

(`genus/{genusName}/notes` is working well)

routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

src/AppBundle/Controller/GenusController.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class GenusController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/genus/{genusName}")
     */
    public function showAction($genusName)
    {
        return $this->render('genus/show.html.twig', array(
            'name' => $genusName,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/genus/{genusName}/notes", name="genus_show_notes")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function getNotesAction($genusName)
    {
        $notes = [
            ['id' => 1, 'username' => 'AquaPelham', 'avatarUri' => '/images/leanna.jpeg', 'note' => 'Octopus asked me a riddle, outsmarted me', 'date' => 'Dec. 10, 2015'],
            ['id' => 2, 'username' => 'AquaWeaver', 'avatarUri' => '/images/ryan.jpeg', 'note' => 'I counted 8 legs... as they wrapped around me', 'date' => 'Dec. 1, 2015'],
            ['id' => 3, 'username' => 'AquaPelham', 'avatarUri' => '/images/leanna.jpeg', 'note' => 'Inked!', 'date' => 'Aug. 20, 2015'],
        ];
        $data = [
            'notes' => $notes
        ];
        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
}
```

app/Resources/views/genus/show.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Genus {{ name }}{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <h2 class="genus-name">{{ name }}</h2>
    <a href="{{ path('genus_show_notes', {'genusName': name}) }}">Json Notes</a>
    <div class="sea-creature-container">
        <div class="genus-photo"></div>
        <div class="genus-details">
            <dl class="genus-details-list">
                <dt>Subfamily:</dt>
                <dd>Octopodinae</dd>
                <dt>Known Species:</dt>
                <dd>289</dd>
                <dt>Fun Fact:</dt>
                <dd>Octopuses can change the color of their body in just three-tenths of a second!</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notes-container">
        <h2 class="notes-header">Notes</h2>
        <div><i class="fa fa-plus plus-btn"></i></div>
    </div>
    <section id="cd-timeline"></section>
{% endblock %}
```

debug:route http://joxi.ru/Dr8j6YniOx3E26 (sorry, I can paste only url cause of reputation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path in your route configuration does not contain a trailing slash. In order to make your example work you will either need to remove the trailing slash when trying to access your controller (i.e. `/genus/octopus` instead of `/genus/octopus/`) or add the slash to your route config.

Comment: Oh, such easy! Thank's!